# Beanshell values not random for thread

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I've got a problem with trying to randomize some values. In this case I'm using *Random* to select a title from a string list.

```
import java.util.Random;
titles = "Mr,Mrs,Sir,Ms,Dr";
String[] titles = titles.split(",");
Random random = new Random();
String randomValue = titles[random.nextInt(titles.length)];
vars.put("TITLE", randomValue);
```

Above works fine for a single run of a thread but if you're looping then it stops generating new values. If I run multiple threads then it generates different values.

Comment: Add actual and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My expectation is that your Beanshell script fails somewhere somehow, most probably you're facing a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when trying to overwrite `titles` variable value by something which changes its type.

You can amend your code to look like:

```
import java.util.Random;
titles = "Mr,Mrs,Sir,Ms,Dr";
String[] titles2 = titles.split(",");
Random random = new Random();
String randomValue = titles2[random.nextInt(titles2.length)];
vars.put("TITLE", randomValue);
```

and it should resolve your issue.

A better solution would be migrating to a [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as [it's recommended to do so since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), Groovy has better performance comparing to Beanshell hence you should be able to re-use your existing code.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using JSR223 preprocessor and it worked fine.